# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':expo-modules-core:debugCompileClasspath'.Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1

Tags: react-native, expo

We are trying to update React Native to version `0.73` with "expo": "50.0.3". But we get this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':expo-modules-core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1.
     Required by:
         project :expo-modules-core
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
           Constraint path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 0.3.0
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.6' (debugVariantDefaultApiPublication) --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'

   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}.
     Required by:
         project :expo-modules-core
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
           Constraint path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 0.3.0
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.6' (debugVariantDefaultApiPublication) --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'

   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :expo-modules-core > com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.6
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni' that satisfies the version constraints:
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
           Constraint path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:{strictly 0.3.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 0.3.0
           Dependency path 'host.exp.exponent:expo-modules-core:1.11.8' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-android:0.72.6' (debugVariantDefaultApiPublication) --> 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0'
```

I have somehow fix this by patching `expo-modules-core` `android/build.gradle` file like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...

  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-android'

  compileOnly 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
  implementation("com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1") <- added this line
```

But it is somehow tricky and doesn't seem like the correct solution to me ‍♀️. Does anybody have the same problem?

Also no issue was found in the expo repo: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I can't even fix it using the patch-package method!

Comment: well...I have somehow fixed this by patching expo-modules-core android/build.gradle file like this: `dependencies {
  ...

  implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-android'

  compileOnly 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1'
  implementation("com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.5.1") <- added this line` ... But it is somehow tricky and doesn't seem like the correct solution to me :/.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could fix this issue was by downgrading `expo` to version `49.0.22`. I am running react-native version `0.72.10`.

Comment: yeah same for us... we decided to wait with upgrade to 0.73, until it will be more stable with all libraries

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a dependency conflict, you should try to run `npx expo-doctor`
Maybe expo-modules-core version is not correct for your expo and react-native version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).